# Find a sequence of matching words in two strings

Tags: objective-c, string, cocos2d-iphone, compare

I have a problem when comparing two arrays of NSString. 
One of the arrays keeps changing, because it is linked to an UITextField, so when you write anything, it is stored in the array.

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt{


NSString *level = (NSString *)gameData[2]; //this doesn't change. example: "one two three .."

NSString *text = (NSString *)tf.text; //text field keeps changing as I write

NSArray *separatedText = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSArray *separatedLevel = [level componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

I want to check if any of the words that you are writing match with any of the words that are stored in the level array.
For example,
Level is: "Comparing two strings"
And I write "comparing"
So this method, would return that 1 word is matching. So if I write "comparing two" it returns that 2 words are matching.

I tried with this code:

```
for (int i=0;i<separatedText.count;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<separatedLevel.count;j++){
        if (![separatedText[i] caseInsensitiveCompare:separatedLevel[j]]){
            NSLog(@"OK");

            }

        }else{
            NSLog(@"NO");
        }


    }

}
```

but it is not working properly.
Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

caseInsensitiveCompare does not return a BOOL, but it works for me that way.
If I run this code with level "one two three" and text "one" the result is:

```
OK
NO
NO
```

And with "one two" the result is:

```
NO
OK
NO
```

When it should be OK OK NO

**EDIT 2**

Sorry if I expressed myself wrong.

The result that I want is "OK OK NO" when I write 2 words that match
Or maybe, a result that returns the number of matches.
So with the previous example:

Level: "one two three"
Text: "one two"
Result: "2 matching words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to increment `i` if you find a match, and keep a count of the sequential matches you have made.

<sub>I have implemented it as a C Function here, but you should have no trouble converting it to an Objective-C class method</sub>:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSUInteger numSequentialMatches(NSString *s1, NSString *s2) {
    NSUInteger sequence = 0, highestSequence = 0;
    NSArray *a1 = [s1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray *a2 = [s2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < a1.count; i++) {
        for (NSInteger j = 0; j < a2.count; j++) {
            if ([a1[i] caseInsensitiveCompare:a2[j]] == NSOrderedSame) {
                if (i < a1.count)
                    i++;
                if (++sequence > highestSequence)
                    highestSequence = sequence;
            } else {
                sequence = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return highestSequence;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%lu", numSequentialMatches(@"one two three", @"one"));
        NSLog(@"%lu", numSequentialMatches(@"one two three", @"one two"));
    }
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o array array.m -framework Foundation
$ ./array
2013-10-03 15:21:08.166 array[17194:707] 1
2013-10-03 15:21:08.167 array[17194:707] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using fast enumerator:-

```
NSArray *separatedText=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",nil];
NSArray *separatedLevel=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",nil];
NSString *str1;
NSString *str2;
BOOL isMatch;

for (str1 in separatedText){
    isMatch=NO;
    for (str2 in separatedLevel){
        if (![str1 caseInsensitiveCompare:str2])
        {
            NSLog(@"OK");
            isMatch=YES;
        }
    }
    if (isMatch==NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: See the code is correct but how its working is it is first traversing the all second for loop element with 1 item of first for loop, like that it is traversing. So output is coming as you edited.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself well. See my edit 2. Thanks for the help

Comment: Now i got your problem, i have modified again please try now

Comment: Also it is done by very simple way. You can modify the array value accordingly.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSPredicates` instead.

```
 NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains '%@'",separatedText];

        NSArray *filteredArray  = [separatedLevel filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate ];
        if ([filteredArray count] == 0){
            NSLog(@"No elements");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Have elements");
        }
```